# Do the points mean anything?

Tags: kingdom-for-princess-iv

I am playing My Kingdom for the Princess IV, and noticed that at the end of a level I am awarded points for the level. I find this odd, because the game doesn't seem to use them for anything. (Completing the level before nightfall seems to be the main goal, which gets you a gold heart/star/thing on that level).

Do the points matter? Do they do anything? Or are they just there?

Comment: For what it's worth, points don't mean anything in 90% of the Mario platformer games either, since 1-ups are tied to coins, not raw score.

Comment: Yeah, I know, it's just unusual for TM games to have a point system.